# Method declaration in an interface definition

Tags: c++, com

```
[id(203), helpstring("method LoadPolyDataXml")] HRESULT LoadPolyDataXml([out,retval]CComBSTR bstrPolyData);
```

I get an error as:

> Error 1 error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "CComBSTR"

How to solve?

Comment: Make sure the header defining `CComBSTR` is included and on the search path...

Answer (score 2):

please, replace CComBSTR with BSTR*. The CComBSTR should not be used in idl files

then the usage would be

```
CComBSTR data;
LoadPolyDataXml(&data)
```

the implementation could be

```
HRESULT LoadPolyDataXml(BSTR* pData);
{
  if (pData == 0) return E_POINTER;

  CComBSTR xml;
  // ... reading xml here
  *pData = xml.Detach()
  or 
  *pData = ::SysAllocString(string data here)

}
```

do not forget to check for out of memory error